# Can decorators infer the parameter types of function?

Tags: typescript

I used to encapsulate a set of methods for listening to events and triggering callback:

```js
interface EventMap {
  'system.notice': (event: { id: number }) => void;
  'system.message': (event: { message: string }) => void;
}

function addEvent<T extends keyof EventMap>(name: T, callback: EventMap[T]) {
  // ...
}

addEvent('system.message', event => {
  // ...
});
```

This will automatically infer the parameter type when calling the `addEvent` method.

Recently, I refactored this method with a decorator:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';

interface EventMap {
  'system.notice': (event: { id: number }) => void;
  'system.message': (event: { message: string }) => void;
}

function Event(name: keyof EventMap): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target, key, descriptor) {
    if (!descriptor.value) {
      throw new Error('Event Error');
    }
    Reflect.defineMetadata(EVENT_METADATA, name, descriptor.value);
    // ...
  };
}

class Plugin {
  @Event('system.message')
  onMessage(event: { message: string }) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

But in this way, the `onMessage` method must explicitly define the parameter type of the function.

I have consulted many materials, but I have not found a similar solution.

Although I can implement it through `interface` or `type`, I am more curious about whether there is a way to achieve automatic type derivation.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea about how to achieve this. A possible suggestion is to use TypedPropertyDescriptor to build a type safe method.

```
interface EventMap {
  'system.notice': (event: { id: number }) => void;
  'system.message': (event: { message: string }) => void;
}

const EVENT_METADATA = Symbol('event');

function Event<T extends keyof EventMap>(name: T) {
  return function (
    target: any,
    key: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<EventMap[T]>,
  ) {
    if (!descriptor.value) {
      throw new Error('Event Error');
    }
    Reflect.defineMetadata(EVENT_METADATA, name, descriptor.value);
    // ...
  };
}

class Plugin {
  @Event('system.message')
  // any type is not `{ message: string }` will make error
  onMessage(event: { message: string }) {
    // ...
  }
}
```